# How to bind keyboard events with div elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a simple react project in order to get some hand-on experience with the library.

My desire is to create a simple UI with blanks and let users type in via keyboard.

below is what I've been up to so far

```
function FillTheBlanks(props) {
  const blanks = new Array(5).fill(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState([]);

  function InsertInput() {
    setInput([...input, "a"]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        {blanks.map((blank, index) => (
          <div className="blank" key={index}>
            {input[index]}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button className="button" onClick={InsertInput}>
        add "a" to the div
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPyTv.png)

It did what I told it to do,adding "a" to each blank when I click the button.

now I want to adjust it to fill in the blanks from what I  directly type from my keyboard but I can't figure it out how to do so.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the [onKeyPress](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) event on your outer div for example.
Then create a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), pass it to the div, focus the div on render with [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

```js
function FillTheBlanks() {
  const blanks = new Array(5).fill(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState([]);

  function InsertInput() {
    setInput([...input, "a"]);
  }

  const onKeyPress = (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
    setInput([...input, e.key]);
  };

  const ref = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div tabIndex={1} onKeyPress={onKeyPress} ref={ref}>
      <div className="container">
        {blanks.map((blank, index) => (
          <div className="blank" key={index}>
            {input[index]}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button className="button" onClick={InsertInput}>
        add "a" to the div
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If there is a border around the div modify the [`:focus`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) style.

Comment: It works!! thanks Julian. but I do have a question. how do I know where  to put onKeyPress ? I tried  to change the positions of the attributes from the  outmost div(onKeyPress  and ref) to inner divs and it didn't work anymore.I couldn't figure out why

Comment: Hm, in theory that should work, you changed the ref too? And is there anything else being focused on the page on render?

Comment: OK,it worked now. I think the reason it didn't work is because I  moved only  just onKeyPress and ref  and left the tabIndex alone in the outmost div (I experimented tabIndex first and learned how it affect my css  properties so I left it there as in the example and moved onKeyPress and ref around to see how they'd affect my component. It didn't focus anything on the page but then I tied 3 of them up together again and placed them on inner div/innermost div and it worked.)if my guess is correct, Do tabindex, onkeypress and ref  always have to be all together in the same element?

Comment: Yes, they should be together, not 100% sure if that is fully needed, but tabindex is needed for an element that gets focused.

Answer (score 0):

The general way of doing this in react or not is to use events, and specifically here, [KeyboardEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

```js
function FillTheBlanks(props) {
  const blanks = new Array(5).fill(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState([]);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    const keyName = event.key;

     if (keyName === 'Control') {
      // do not alert when only Control key is pressed.
      return;
     }
     insertInput(keyName) // calling your function here
  }, false);

  function insertInput(char) {  // dont name single functions in caps, use camelcase
    setInput([...input, char]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        {blanks.map((blank, index) => (
          <div className="blank" key={index}>
            {input[index]}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      //<button className="button" onClick={InsertInput}>
      //  add "a" to the div
      //</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note though that you probably do not want to create your EventListener here, as this seems like a down-level component and you might needlessly be duplicating it as you scale your application.  Consider how user input in general is a pretty "global" layer, does not know of your apps hierarchy, and as such, should be passed down from the highest level component you have.

Also remember to validate user input as much as possible, note the check above for just the Ctl key.  You probably want to narrow down the possible input to letters and digits:

```js
if(keyName.match(/[\w\d]/)) {
// you have a single char or single digit
}
```